# How to write a background service to get latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

I need to write a background service to get latitude and longitude values. I have an Android application in which it has to find where the user is currently. Is there any way to programmatically get the latitude and longitude values from the system services (or some program)?

Comment: if you want to write in Javascript then my answer can be useful.

Comment: this answer can help on how-to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5772782/492918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LocationManager`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) covers this.

Comment: "sample application" link not found.