# GPS coordinates not being retrieved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, location

HI i have been trying to run this code from an example in a book but all i get is is the null value being passed to the variable and so i only get the message as "Your Current Position is : no location found

The manifest file is as below

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

The main.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myLocationText"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Lastly is the MainActivity.java

```
    package com.snooze.android.geopositioning;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }
    public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) 
    {
String latLongString;
TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    if (location != null) 
    {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    latLongString = "Lat:" + String.valueOf(lat) + "\nLong:" + String.valueOf(lng);
    } 
    else
    {
    latLongString = "No location found";
    }
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }
    }
```

This is my first project so i am unfamiliar with a few of the workings but i copied everything as the book said but it does not work. Have tried various things on many sites, as well as answers from this forum....but to no avail. 
What i think is that the co-ordinates are not being passed to the variables.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`or `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to use the GPS in your manifest file

Answer (score 1):

try this one from commonsguy, it is easy to implement/customize and works like charm;

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

Answer (score 0):

You should use indents and paragraphs in your code, makes it more readable.

Also, for showing a Map, there is a '[MapActivity](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html)', which already provides some functionality for you (like zooming for example).

To make this work, you also need the 'Google API'-library in your Android Manifest, and the Internet-Permission is needed (to get the cards). You should read [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) on how to do all that stuff correctly.