# Create an android app that obtains & sends GPS location of user in background

Tags: android, service, gps, location

Sir,
I want to create such an android app that:

- First,When we open that app,Then it Starts a background service and,
- Then gets GPS location of user.
- After that, It POSTS (*POST Method of HTTP*) the returned LATTITUDE and LONGITUDE to PHP Page.

If someone genius can provide me link to do all these,
I will highly greatful to his/her......

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a background service to get latitude and longitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640973/how-to-write-a-background-service-to-get-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: @AnirudhSharma No, I not found my answer....

Answer (score 1):

This is not a platform to ask such broad questions. But as I have just finished an exact implementation, I can give you hints and links to complete your task.

[Servies](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html): As you are probably already aware, you will need to have a service to send GPS data in background.

[Location Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html): Location listener helps you listen the location of a user. It provides a method `onLocationChanged(Location location)` which will be fired anytime the location of user is changed on given conditions.

For your third task, use your API and send latitude and longitude from the location object provided by `onLocationChanged(Location location)` with the help of `location.getLatitude()` and `location.getLongitude()`.

Comment: Ok but i Googled a lot and not found any exact answers

Comment: Try this

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/